# testng suite second test fail -> nullpointerexception

Tags: java, testng

I have some dao tests i want to execute using testng suite
I am initializing all daos in `@BeforeSuite` but only the first test can use the daos , others tests generate nullpointer when calling to a dao

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you very much

Base test :

```
 public class BaseTest {

    protected DocumentDaoImpl documentDao;
    protected UserDaoImpl userDao;


  @BeforeSuite
  public void beforeSuite() {
        EntityManagerUtil.setPersistenceUnitName("db_test"); //initialize entityManagerFactory once for all tests as well as daos
        documentDao = DAOFactory.getDocumentDAO();
        userDao = DAOFactory.getUserDao();
  }

  @AfterSuite
  public void afterSuite() {
    EntityManagerUtil.closeEntityManagerFactory();
  }
}
```

Test 1 :

```
public class DocumentDaoImplTest extends BaseTest{

    @Test(dataProviderClass = DocumentDataProvider.class, dataProvider = DocumentDataProvider.ONE_DOCUMENT_PROVIDER)
    public void findByMatricule(Document document) {
        documentDao.create(document);
        Document result = documentDao.findByMatricule(document.getMatricule());
        Assert.assertNotNull(result);
        Assert.assertEquals(result.getMatricule(), document.getMatricule());
    }
}
```

Test 2 :

```
public class UserDaoImplTest extends BaseTest{

    @Test(dataProviderClass = UserDataProvider.class, dataProvider = UserDataProvider.ONE_USER_PROVIDER)
    public void findByDocumentId(User user) {
        // nullpointer userDao
        userDao.create(user);
        User result = userDao.findByDocumentId(user.getDocumentId());
        Assert.assertNotNull(result);
        Assert.assertEquals(result.getDocumentId(), user.getDocumentId());
    }

}
```

testng.xml

```
<test name="DAOTest">
    <packages>
        <package name="com.dev.test.dao"/>
    </packages> 
</test>
```

Stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dev.test.dao.UserDaoImplTest.findByDocumentId(UserDaoImplTest.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
```

What i am doing wrong ?
The tests works if run independently , only fails when i run all at once

Thank you very much

Comment: You have to provide stack of that exception. In other case, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: @Krzysiek . Done . Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to rework your tests:

`@BeforeSuite` is only called once by suite.
You have 2 classes then the first has the dao instanced, the other not (NPE in this case).

One option is to use `static` for your dao.
Another solution could be to put `documentDao = DAOFactory.getDocumentDAO();` into `@BeforeClass`.
But you can find many other (better) solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much. Static and @BeforeClass works both